# GNOME's touchpad and mouse settings completely changed after installing XFCE4 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, xfce, mouse, desktop-environment

On my Ubuntu 20.04 installation, in addition to GNOME, I installed XFCE as an additional DE. After doing this (and not changing any settings) I noticed that my touchpad began behaving differently across **all** desktop environments. So when switching back to GNOME, the XFCE default touchpad settings are still applied.

Specifically:

- Natural scrolling can no longer be enabled in the horizontal direction.
- Accelaration feels different to GNOME's preset.
- No more palm rejection when typing.
- Scrolling inertia enabled (pages keep scrolling for a bit after releasing fingers from touchpad)

Things I have tried:

- Purging XFCE from my system.
- Reinstalling GNOME
- Reinstalling ubuntu-desktop
- Searching the dconf editor for relevant settings which I've seen other forum posts telling me to change.
- Manual changes using xinput, but these aren't persistent, and I would like to find the exact config file causing these issues.

How can I get back to GNOME's default touchpad settings?

Comment: Check the ```/var/log/Xorg.*.log``` files 1st.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the synaptic driver that overrides all touchpad settings in Gnome. It is installed as a dependency of the XFCE desktop meta-package and then left behind even if the rest is uninstalled. Uninstall it and purge all its configuration and all will work again.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all of Gnome's touchpad settings in `dconf editer`. just do a search for "touch". Note: any setting you modify will also have a switch to reset it do default, as well... so you should be able to return these settings to their default in `dconf-editor`.

You could also reset *all* of Gnome's settings to default via `gsettings`...

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome
```

- However, obviously that will hose all of your settings in Gnome.

EDIT: you should also look in dconf editor at Ubuntu-specific settings. they may have their own modifications and touch related settings, as well.

Another/better approach might be to see if a new user account has the same problem -> this might indicate the problem is elsewhere (xorg related setting/config or some system level config)... but at least it would rule out the problem being in gnome's settings (dconf/gsettings) and also rule out it being caused by a setting in your user's `/home/.config` configuration files.

I think the other comment about checking `/var/log/Xorg.*.log` is important to do, as well. You should do that too. If you see something that looks like an error; you could post it on pastebin and link to it here.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already searched through all the settings in the dconf editor, and tried what you suggested, resetting all of GNOME's settings. I have even reinstalled GNOME and ubuntu-desktop, as I say in my question.

Comment: ah ok. ya, i mentioned resetting gsettings because reinstalling isn't enough + other DE's that use gsettings mess with gnome's settings too, sometimes... did you try a new user?